# Unexplained bug at Android Firebase RecyclerView with Button pressed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and a button for 'Binding' each item (Moving to another child at the DB).

Most of the time it works well, but sometimes i'm receiving indexOutOfBounds Exception.

This is a screen shot:

[image: css]

When I press at 'BIND' at the top recycler view item, i'm receiving this bug.
I made it print this line:

```
Log.d("dDebug","Almost bug! Size: " + ((MissionAdapter) MissionAdapter.this).mSnapshots.size() + " , index: " + missionPosition);
```

And it prints this:

```
D/dDebug: Almost bug! Size: 1 , index: 1
```

Here you can see the bug - size 1, index 1, so it will have indexOutOfBounds.

This is the code:

```
    public class AvailableFragmentPilot extends Fragment {

    private String TAG = "dDEBUG";
    private RecyclerView mavailableList;

    private DatabaseReference mAvailableMissionsDb, mPendingMissionsDb;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog mSubmitMsnProgress;

    private String mCurrent_pilot_id;

    private View mMainView;

//    Query queries;

    public AvailableFragmentPilot() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_of_recycler_view_user, container, false);

        mavailableList = (RecyclerView)mMainView.findViewById(R.id.mission_recycler_user);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mSubmitMsnProgress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

        mCurrent_pilot_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mAvailableMissionsDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Missions").child("Available");
        mAvailableMissionsDb.keepSynced(true);

        mPendingMissionsDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Missions").child("Pending");
        mPendingMissionsDb.keepSynced(true);

//        queries = mAvailableMissionsDb.orderByChild("user_uid").equalTo(mCurrent_pilot_id);

        mavailableList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mavailableList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return mMainView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mavailableList.setAdapter(new MissionAdapter(mAvailableMissionsDb));
    }

    private class MissionAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Mission, AvailableFragmentPilot.MissionsViewHolder> {

        public MissionAdapter(Query queries){
            super(Mission.class, R.layout.missions_single_layout, AvailableFragmentPilot.MissionsViewHolder.class, queries);
        }

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(AvailableFragmentPilot.MissionsViewHolder missionViewHolder, final Mission missionModel, final int missionPosition) {
            Log.d(TAG, "inside populateViewHolder" + missionModel.getType() + " , " + missionModel.getDescription());
            missionViewHolder.setMissionName(missionModel.getType());
            missionViewHolder.setMissionDescription(missionModel.getDescription());
            missionViewHolder.setMissionStatus(missionModel.getStatus());
            missionViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Mission clickedMission = null;
                    if (((MissionAdapter) MissionAdapter.this).mSnapshots.size()>missionPosition){
                        clickedMission = AvailableFragmentPilot.MissionAdapter.this.getItem(missionPosition);
                        Log.d("dDebug","Ein bug. Size: " + ((MissionAdapter) MissionAdapter.this).mSnapshots.size() + " , index: " + missionPosition + " , mission: " + clickedMission.getType() + ": " + clickedMission.getDescription());
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d("dDebug","Almost bug! Size: " + ((MissionAdapter) MissionAdapter.this).mSnapshots.size() + " , index: " + missionPosition);
                    }
                    if (clickedMission != null){ // for the sake of being extra-safe
//                        String url_str = getRef(missionPosition).toString();
//                        String uuid_for_mission = url_str.split("/")[5];
                        Log.d(TAG,"The button was pressed for mission: " + clickedMission.getType() + " , uid: " + missionModel.getMission_uid());
//                        removeMission(uuid_for_mission);
                        bindMission(clickedMission);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void bindMission(final Mission mission){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("Mission bind");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to bind this mission?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                mAvailableMissionsDb.child(mission.getMission_uid()).setValue(null);

                final HashMap<String, String> missionMap = new HashMap<>();
                missionMap.put("username", mission.getUsername());
                missionMap.put("user_uid", mission.getUser_uid());
                missionMap.put("mission_uid", mission.getMission_uid());
                missionMap.put("type", mission.getType());
                missionMap.put("status", "Pending");
                missionMap.put("description", mission.getDescription());
                missionMap.put("x", String.valueOf(mission.getX()));
                missionMap.put("y", String.valueOf(mission.getY()));
                missionMap.put("pilot_uid", mCurrent_pilot_id);

                mPendingMissionsDb.child(mission.getMission_uid()).setValue(missionMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
//                            Log.d("dDebug","Before");
                            mSubmitMsnProgress.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ("Bind to mission " + mission.getType()),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("dDebug","Painting in Red 1");
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("dDebug","ok, not binding");
                    }
                });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        builder.create().show();
    }

    public static class MissionsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        Button button ;

        public MissionsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            button = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.mission_single_button);
            button.setText("BIND");
        }

        public void setMissionName(String name){
            TextView mMissionNameView = mView.findViewById(R.id.mission_single_name);
            mMissionNameView.setText(name);
        }

        public void setMissionStatus(String status){
            TextView mMissionStatusView = mView.findViewById(R.id.mission_single_status);
            mMissionStatusView.setText(status);
            if (status.equals("Available")){
                mMissionStatusView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));;
            } else {
                mMissionStatusView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));;
            }
        }

        public void setMissionDescription(String description){
            TextView mMissionDescriptionView = mView.findViewById(R.id.mission_single_description);
            mMissionDescriptionView.setText(description);
        }
    }
}
```

**In addition** - sometimes I will have 5 items, I'll press at the most upper one, (Should be index 0!) - and the SECOND item is being moved (at index 1).
So it means that probarely something is wrong with the way i'm getting the item that was clciked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rookie recycler view mistake: the view holder can move around and be reused (thus changing its position) while the `onClick` callback will only store a reference to the original position. To fix that, use `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()`.